# graph-tool (docker): no module name 'ipython_genutils'

Tags: graph-tool

I am trying to install and run graph-tool in jupyter notebooks using docker by following the following instructions: https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#installing-using-docker

My computer is running windows 10 home.

## Steps Taken (on windows command prompt)

1. run `docker pull tiagopeixoto/graph-tool` in the windows cmd

- I successfully pull the docker image

2. run `docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -it -u user -w /home/user tiagopeixoto/graph-tool bash`

- successfully runs

2. run `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0`

- I try to run the above command and get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/sbin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in 
> from notebook.notebookapp import main   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/**init**.py", line 27, in
>
> from .nbextensions import install_nbextension   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 20,
> in 
> from ipython_genutils.py3compat import string_types, cast_unicode_py2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'ipython_genutils'

I've also tried running the same above using docker-machine to create a virtual machine and I the exact same error.

## Steps Taken (using docker-machine)

1. Create a vm in virtualbox:
   `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-cpu-count=4 --virtualbox-disk-size=40960 --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default` (I ran this command in bash)
2. open the command line of the vm from virtualbox and run `docker pull tiagopeixoto/graph-tool`

- I successfully pull the docker image

2. run `docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -it -u user -w /home/user tiagopeixoto/graph-tool bash` from the vm (virtualbox) cmd

- successfully runs

2. run `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0`

- I try to run the above command and get the error (same error as above)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/sbin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in 
> from notebook.notebookapp import main   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/**init**.py", line 27, in
>
> from .nbextensions import install_nbextension   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 20,
> in 
> from ipython_genutils.py3compat import string_types, cast_unicode_py2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'ipython_genutils'

In the virtual machine I also tried installing pip then installing ipython_genutils using the following commands. ipython_genutils successfully installs but I still get the same error as above.

> `tce-load -wi python3.7`

> `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3 -`

> `pip install ipython_genutils`

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue and came up with this workaround for anyone who may be stuck. Please note I am new to Docker and Linux so there may be better methods/practices but this worked for me!

First I ran the image as root rather than "user".

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -it -u root -w /home/user tiagopeixoto/graph-tool bash
```

Then I needed to manually install `pip` as it is not present in the container.

```
pacman -S python-pip
```

Running a quick `pip list` confirms that package `ipython_genutils` is not present.
Googling the error message, I was initially lead to this page: https://github.com/ipython/ipython_genutils/issues/3
Which first suggests installing `jupyter` using `pip`, which will pull `ipython_genutils`.

```
pip install jupyter
```

Running `pip list` now shows `ipython-genutils`. After this, I believe it is good practice in Docker to use limited-perms user accounts, so I switch back to "user" before continuing the tutorial with `su user`. Now I am able to successfully continue and launch the Jupyter server without error.

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0
```